# Git Bash Owner of file

Tags: windows, cygwin, git-bash

Using Git Bash, I ran:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.8.3-preview20130601)

$ whoami
kevinmeredith

$ ls -lrot foo.log
-rw-r--r--    1 kevinmer       29 Nov 25 15:33 foo.log
```

I did not find such a `kevinmer` user:

```
$ ls /cygdrive/c/users | grep -i kevinmer
kevinmeredith
```

Does that mean that `kevinmer` is my user, i.e. `kevinmeredith`?

Comment: I do not think asking two questions in the same ticket is a good idea since some readers may only have answer for one of them and it will make is impossible to select the best answer if no one covers both sub-questions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a windows git, as current cygwin git is 2.8.3.
As such you are looking from two different point of views with different scope and assumption.

If you have not changed your `/etc/passwd` cygwin whoami uses the same user name than windows. `kevinmer` seems just shorted to 8 letters.

ACL Windows Permission are available with `cacls.exe foo.log`, cygwin tries to
represent it in Posix/Unix way and windows git is reporting them in a different way.